# serialize and get object object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I have an object from my query, now i want convert it to string, and send to my json page, but i get `[object object], [object object]`

my query is:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class AjaxProcess : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SouthParsModel.SouthParsEntities db = new SouthParsModel.SouthParsEntities();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string serText = "";

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["get_subcategory_or_product_of_this"]);

        var CatList = from rows in db.Categories
                  where rows.parentid_FK == id
                  select new { rows.id, rows.name, Type = "category"};


Response.Write(serText);
Response.End();
```

Comment: my problem is C#(asp.net programming), for serialization!

Comment: I don't understand your question, you get `[object object]` from what, and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: could you provide the string that is in serText and what you expected

Comment: Aside from informing us you're using webforms, the submitted code doesn't appear to be relevant to the question.  I am confused.  What does your JSON look like?  How is it being submitted?  How are you attempting to deserialize it?

Comment: 'success: function (msg) { if { data = eval("(" + msg + ")"); alert(data); var temp = $("#dvCategory").html(); var _output = ""; for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { _output += temp.replace("%name%", data[i].Name).replace("%id%", data[i].Id); } $(".submenuContainer").html(_output); $(".submenuItems").click(clickEventForCategory); }'

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2045162/codinggorilla) i get true string when i serialize my query, and response.write and response.end(), then when i go to my json code (success:) and get alert, give me object

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JSON.parse(stringhere); when you pass the serialised object to your page?